How can I require table A's rows to have a unique (k1, k2) and k2 is a foreign key of the row referred by k3? k1, k2, and k3 are foreign keys in A
The question that I framed in the question title is a bit convoluted to think about, so here is my actual, specific problem:
I have four relevant tables: course groups, courses, users, and choices. The following rules apply:

A user may choose courses and my server automatically adds them to the choices table.
A user have a maximum of one choice in each course group; that is, the pair "(course group, user)" uniquely identifies one course, if any.
Each course is associated with one and only one course group.

I attempted to use the following schema:
-- Many irrelevant fields have been redacted

CREATE TABLE cgroups (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE courses (
    id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    cgroup TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(cgroup) REFERENCES cgroups(name)
);

CREATE TABLE users (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE choices (
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, courseid), -- Primary key guarantees unique

    userid TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES users(id),

    courseid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(courseid) REFERENCES courses(id),

    -- Which course group does this choice belong to? Primary problem here:
    -- I want to guarantee that the cgroup here corresponds to the cgroup
    -- of the course referenced above.
    cgroup TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(cgroup) REFERENCES cgroups(name),

    -- Attempt to ensure that each user can only choose one course from a cgroup
    UNIQUE (userid, cgroup)
);

The problem here is that choice.cgroup isn't constrained to correspond to courses[choice.courseid].cgroup. How could I express this constraint? Or is there an alternative way to devise a schema to the rules I presented above?

I want to guarantee that the cgroup here corresponds to the cgroup of the course referenced above.. Why? FOREIGN KEY(courseid) REFERENCES courses(id), points at courses where the cgroup is defined for a given courses.id.

The schema created by the following script ensures that each course is associated with exactly one course group, a user can only choose a course once, a user can only choose one course from each group, and the chosen course and group are consistent with the course definition:
CREATE TABLE cgroups (
  id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE courses (
  id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  cgroup_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES cgroups (id),
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (name),
  UNIQUE (id, cgroup_id)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE choices (
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users (id),
  course_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  cgroup_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, course_id), -- Primary key guarantees unique
  -- referencing (course_id, cgroup_id) ensures that the pair are consistent with the course
  FOREIGN key (course_id, cgroup_id) REFERENCES courses (id, cgroup_id),
  -- ensure that each user can only choose one course per cgroup
  -- column order facilitates efficient searches for users with courses in a specific cgroup
  UNIQUE (cgroup_id, user_id)
);

A synthetic primary key, id, has been added to each table (except for choices) to make it easier to update names without having to update every reference to the name. Indexing and searching integer columns is generally much more efficient than for text columns. Since choices is essentially an associative or bridge table, a synthetic key isn't necessary.
One problem with this model is that it becomes difficult to change course and group associations. Restricting a user to selecting a single course from a group seems more like a business concern than a data integrity issue. In general, database models should enforce data integrity and leave business logic to the application.
